# Associated an EIP to an AWS emr cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, terraform

I'm trying to associate an Elastic IP to the master node of an emr_cluster.

I'm using terraform to automize the creation of my cluster.

Actually i didn't find any answers about how to get the master node id after using the terraform function : resource "aws_emr_cluster"

This is a part of my terraform code

```
## Creation de l'EMR
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr_cluster" {
  name          = "${var.cluster_name}"
  release_label = "emr-5.0.0"
  applications  = ["spark","zeppelin"]

  master_instance_type = "${var.master_type_node}"
  core_instance_type   = "${var.core_type_node}"
  core_instance_count  = "${var.number_of_nodes}"

  ec2_attributes {
    # Key pair
    key_name = "keypairemrcluster"
    # Subnet VPC
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
    #les security groups
    emr_managed_master_security_group = "${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"
    # EMR EC2 default Role
    #instance_profile = "${var.instance_profile}"
    instance_profile = "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"
    }


  service_role = "EMR_DefaultRole"

# S3 bucket to write the log files of the job flow
  log_uri = "s3n://bedatalab/logs"
}

############# Creation eip #########
resource "aws_eip" "emr_eip" {
  vpc = true
}

# Association de l elastic IP au cluster
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id = **"MASTER_NODE_ID" ???????**
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.emr_eip.id}"
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your question how to get the hostname of the master node in emr cluster or is your question how to associate an EIP to the master node? The question (as currently worded reads that you want to get the hostname of master node) if you have aws cli setup and you use a tag with a name for the host the cli command is ->   aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id $(aws emr list-clusters --query 'Clusters[?Name=="give-your-cluster-a-name"].Id' --active --output text) --query 'Cluster.MasterPublicDnsName' --output text